# WEKA classifier evaluation

Tags: classification, weka

I'm trying to evaluate the performance of a classifier using 10-fold CV in WEKA. I have 32,000 records split across three different classes, "po", "ng", "ne". 
po: ~950
ng: ~1200
ne: ~30000

How should I split the dataset for performing CV? Am I right in assuming that for CV I should have a roughly equal number of records for each class, so to prevent unfair weighting towards the "ne" class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, no you need not have equal no. of cases in your classes. Not all datasets are balanced. Yes it might give unrealistic answer. The imbalance in the dataset is a common phenomenon but there are few tactics to handle it-:

**1) Resampling the dataset**

Undersampling- Deleting the records of majority class

Oversampling- Adding the records in minority class

you can use SMOTE algorithm to do it for you.

**2) Performance Metrics**

Some metrics like Kappa (or Cohen’s kappa)can work great in which  Classification accuracy is normalized by the imbalance of the classes in the data.

**3) Cost Sensitive Classifier**
Weka has a CostSensitiveClassifier that can wrap any classifier and apply a custom penalty matrix for miss classification.
But the challenge here is how you determine the cost because cost should be domain dependent and not data dependent.

In case of cross-validation, I found this link to be useful.
http://www.marcoaltini.com/blog/dealing-with-imbalanced-data-undersampling-oversampling-and-proper-cross-validation

Hope it helps.